# Using GDAL Warp results in odd pixel sizes and gaps

Tags: python, raster, gdal, topography, pixel

I am mosaicking one meter and three meter rasters to two meters in Python with GDAL Warp using the following code:

```
cl_string = "-of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -tr 2 2 -tap -r near -overwrite \
-multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS"

warp_options = gdal.WarpOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine(cl_string))
warp_name = "warpped.tif"    
ds = gdal.Warp(warp_name, vsis_paths, options = warp_options)
ds = None
```

Which results in the following:
[image]

The image shows half-width pixels and frequently has gaps (not shown here). How can I ensure the pixels have the correct width?

Comment: are you sure you're not looking at e.g., neighboring 3 pixels of the exact same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have odd-sized pixels. I think you have neighboring pixels with equal values. See the marked up portion of your raster with likely pixel boundaries drawn in:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your note and you seem to be correct. I tested this by using cubic, opposed to near, and loaded the raster into a File Geodatabase. Opening the data in ArcMap, the raster appears much more reasonable.